# windows service calling respository of web application to send mails

Tags: c#, windows-services

I have web application MVC
to send emails I want to use windows service.

I have implemented the mail sending section in one of the repositories.

This is the method I have

```
   public class MailQueueRepository:IMailQueueRepository
    {
        private readonly myDbContext _db;
        private readonly IMailSender _mailSender;

        public MailQueueRepository(myDbContext db, IMailSender mailSender)
        {
            _db = db;
            _mailSender = mailSender;
        }


        public void SendMails()
        {
            var mailsToBeSent = _db.MailQueues.Where(a => a.Status == MailStatus.Pending).ToList();
            foreach (var mailToBeSent in mailsToBeSent)
            {
                try
                {
                    mailToBeSent.Status = MailStatus.Sending;
                    _db.SaveChanges();
                    _mailSender.SendSmtpMail(mailToBeSent.ToAddress,mailToBeSent.Subject,mailToBeSent.Body);
                    mailToBeSent.Status = MailStatus.Sent;
                    mailToBeSent.LastTryDate = DateTime.Now;
                    _db.SaveChanges();
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    mailToBeSent.Status = MailStatus.Failed;
                    mailToBeSent.NumRetries ++;
                    _db.SaveChanges();
                }
            }

        }
    }
```

I wanted to call this function from windows service 
this is what I have done

```
public partial class MailService : ServiceBase
{
    private object _lock = new object();
    private static bool RUNNING = false;
    private readonly Timer timerTick = null;
    private readonly IMailQueueRepository _mailSender;

    public MailService()
    {
        _mailSender = new MailQueueRepository(new myDbContext(), new SmtpMailSender());

        int sendInterval = int.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["check_interval"].ToString());
        timerTick = new Timer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(sendInterval).TotalMilliseconds);
        timerTick.Elapsed += timerTick_Elapsed;

        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void timerTick_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (RUNNING) return;
        lock (_lock)
        {
            if (RUNNING) return;
            RUNNING = true;
            //add try catch here and always unlock
            try
            {                           
                _mailSender.SendMails();
                RUNNING = false;                         
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {                         
                System.Threading.Monitor.Exit(_lock);
            }
        }
    }

    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        base.OnStart(args);
        if (timerTick != null)
        {
            timerTick.Start();
        }
    }

    protected override void OnStop()
    {
        if (timerTick == null) return;
        timerTick.Stop();
        timerTick.Dispose();
    }
}
```

and the Program.cs

```
static class Program
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The main entry point for the application.
    /// </summary>
    static void Main()
    {
        ServiceBase[] ServicesToRun;
        ServicesToRun = new ServiceBase[] 
        { 
            new MailService()
        };
        ServiceBase.Run(ServicesToRun);
    }
}
```

But right now when I run this service, my mails are not sent.

Am I doing it the wrong way.
What should be done?

Comment: You should NOT manually unlock the monitor on `_lock`. The `lock()` statement does this for you. You SHOULD make that a `finally` block and set `RUNNING=false`, or the first exception you get will stop your service permanently.

Comment: done but still, not working. In my `MailService` class's constructor am I initializing `_mailSender` the wrong way? `_mailSender = new MailQueueRepository(new myDbContext(), new SmtpMailSender());`

Comment: What error code or exception you are getting? Please include details in your question. Also, you are swallowing all exceptions in try/catch blocks, which is not good. I would suggest starting by adding code to log details of the exceptions.